# Change view via ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm new to MVVM. I'm trying to figure out easiest way to change view from ViewModel. In fragment part I have navigation to next fragment

```
  fun nextFragment(){
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_memory_to_memoryEnd)
}
```

But I cannot call it from ViewModel. AFAIK it is not even possible and it destroys the conception of ViewModel.

I wanted to call fun nextFragment() when this condition in ViewModel is True

```
if (listOfCheckedButtonsId.size >= 18){
    Memory.endGame()
}
```

**Is there any simple way to change Views depending on values in ViewModel?**

Comment: add the navController to the viewModel

Comment: @DominikWuttke It seems I need to get fragment to findNavController. Is this possible, or did you have something else on your mind?

Comment: You should use a liveData and observe it from your fragment, when the condition is True, you can set the value to the LiveData, and your fragment will get the change, and you can call your nextFragment function

Comment: @GorkyMuñoz Thanks for your respond. I created a observer and MutableLiveData boolean in view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gorky's respond I figured out how to do that.

In Fragment I created observer

```
sharedViewModel.changeView.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Boolean> { hasFinished ->
        if (hasFinished) nextFragment()
    })
```

I created changeView variable in ViewModel. When

```
 var changeView = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

change to **true**, observer call function.

source:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data#6